# dimension of the sum of two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\dim( U + V)=\dim( U) + \dim(V) - \dim( U \cap V)$

where U and V are linear subspaces and $U+V$ is algebraic sum (the least linear space that contains both $U$ and $V$).

In the case of two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is this correct to state that

$\dim( U + V)=\dim( U) + \dim(V) - \dim( U \cap V) = 2 + 2 - 1 = 3$

if planes are not parallel, because $U \cap V$ is a **line** and the dimension of **line** is 1?

Is this correct to state that

$\dim( U + V)=\dim( U) + \dim(V) - \dim( U \cap V) = 2 + 2 - 2 = 2$

because we consider just a *representation* of a plane and all planes parallel are considered equal and represented by a single plane which contains  vector $(0,0,0)$, so then $U \cap V = U = V$?

Comment: What are $U,V,+$?

Comment: Subspaces need to contain the origin. You'll never have subspaces that have empty intersection (you can have trivial intersection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I looked at vector spaces, but if $U$ and $V$ are parallel, isn't $\text{dim}(U \cap V) = 2$?

Comment: this answer currently looks odd, as his question states that this has dimension $2$ -- but it appears he has recently edited that into the original post.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer, though it is hardly complete, because it gave me a direction

Comment: Didn't have required rep for a comment at the time, thought I'd throw something out there that might help. :)

Answer (score 1):

We don't consider arbitrary planes here: $\dim$ is something which makes sense for subspaces, i.e. planes which go through the origin.

This way, if $U$ and $V$ are parallel, they are actually the same and this is why $\dim (U \cap V)=2$, as you can see with

$$\dim (U + V) = \dim U + \dim V - \dim (U + V)= \dim U + \dim U - \dim U = 2,$$

but also just via $U+V= U$.

This does not apply to planes which don't go through the origin - these do not have a meaning of 'dimension'.